# Q: Does VS2015 Community Update 3 compile Windows UWP Apps for Win10 Build 10586 on Win7SP1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, cross-compiling, windows-7-x64

I have a PC with Windows 7 SP1 (64bit) that I have been using to build a Windows store app.  I've been using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 2.  This worked great until I applied Visual Studio Update 3 and the latest Windows SDK (14393).

When I target the previous release (10586), I get the following error when I try to compile a C# project:

---

*Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2151,5): error APPX0002: Task 'GenerateAppxPackageRecipe' failed. 0x7F - Failed to load MRM support library.*

---

(I have a C++ UWP project in the same solution and it compiles into a DLL without any issues.)

I've tried reinstalling VS2015 Update 2, reinstalling VS2015 Update 3, repairing Visual Studio, repairing the Windows SDK for 10586.  None of these worked.

I know the latest Windows 10 SDK does not support Windows 7 SP1; however, does this apply to ***all previous*** Windows 10 SDK's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2151,5): error APPX0002: Task 'GenerateAppxPackageRecipe' failed. 0x7F - Failed to load MRM support library.*

This is a known issue in Windows 10 SDK (ver. 10.0.14393.33) which is included in Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3. And it has been fixed in **QFE Build 10.0.14393.795**.

> This non-security update includes quality improvements:
>
> - **Addressed issue where developers could not build UWP apps on Windows 7 because MRMSupport.dll failed to load.**
> - Addressed issue where MidlRT and MDMerge failed to run on Windows 7
> - Addressed issue where SDK setup failed to install on Windows
> - Addressed issue where deploying a legacy Store app to a 8.1 Phone caused Visual Studio to crash
> - Addressed issue where application data was not preserved across remote debugging sessions when apps were getting un-registered

For more info, please see [Windows SDK and emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).

To solve this problem, please go to *Add/Remove Programs* and Uninstall **Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.14393.33**. Then reinstall the  [10.0.14393.795 version](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=838916) from *Windows SDK and emulator archive*. After this, you should be able to build the UWP app with no error.

However, on Windows 7, with Visual Studio 2015, the official support for Windows Universal is "**Build only**". A lot of other Visual Studio features are degraded. So if you are developing Windows Universal Apps, **Windows 10 is strongly recommended**. For more info, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42824713).

Answer (score 5):

Finally, after days of repairing and re-installing, I finally fixed this.

Step 1: Assuming you installed Visual Studio in the default location, goto the following folder: ***C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage***

Step 2: Rename ***Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets*** to something else.  I added "-old" after Package.

Step 3: Clean the solution.

Step 4: Confirm you are targeting Windows 10 Build 10586.

Step 5: Build the solution.

My targets file is dated May 31, 2016 before I even installed Visual Studio 2015.  Before I did these steps, I also deleted everything in the bin/Debug folder but I'm not sure if this helped or not.

Comment: While that does allow it to compile, it does not regenerate the Targets file. Is this going to break something else?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if this will break something else.My main PC is a Windows 10 PC.  When I'm offsite, I have access to a Windows 7 PC.  To keep my development going, I installed VS2015 on the Windows 7 PC so I could write source code and confirm it compiles.  I use Git to keep the source code in sync across the two systems.